# Is there a function in vhdl to check whether a port is connected or open?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, it is allowed to leave an output port of a component open. Is there a function to detect that from within the component so that other hardware could be generated?

I don't want to wait on the optimisation step, since I would like to modify the hardware in case a port is left open.

Specifically, I'm generating a component with differential output, in which I would like to include a OBUFDS in case both _P and _N are connected, and I don't want to include that component in case the _N is left open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isnt. A generic would normally be used for this.